# Separate array output into a <ul>

Tags: php, html, array

I have this snippet of PHP which looks at each post and displays the categories it is listed in on the archive page BUT I want to separate them either with 
 or in a  OR even just with a comma and a space would work. Thanks

```
      <?php if ( ! $jobs ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><?php _e( 'You do not have any active   listings.', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php foreach ( $jobs as $job ) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach ( $job_dashboard_columns as $key => $column ) : ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                            <?php if ('job_title' === $key ) : ?>
                                <?php if ( $job->post_status == 'publish' ) : ?>
                          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $job->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $job->post_title; ?></a><br> Job Status: 


<?php

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $job->ID, 'job_listing_category' ); 

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  echo $term->name;
} 
?>

<?php else : ?>

                          <?php echo $job->post_title; ?> <small>  (<?php the_job_status( $job ); ?>)</small>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You're missing the `if` part of your code so it errors out.

Comment: Sorry didn't include it - I will edit the original post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` loop isn't needed. This will list out all job categories separated by a comma.

```
$terms  = wp_get_post_terms( $job->ID, 'job_listing_category' );

echo implode( ', ', wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name' ) );

// Marketing, Sales, Finance, Support
```

Comment: Awesome that's the ticket, would I be able to add a <br> into that at all? Or is a comma the limit?

Comment: You can add whatever you want. Just replace the `implode( ', '` with `implode( '<br>'`.